# How to call a function repeatedly in a fixed interval using php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a function insertdata() which is written in php. It is taking the values from one table of database and then inserting it into another table of database.

I want to repeat this with a fixed time interval till stop button is clicked.
Please help me ..

I tried using setInterval, but its working only once. 
Also I used

```
if(isset($_POST['stopbutton']))
    $stop=1;
else
    $stop=0;

function insertdata(){
    while ($stop=0) {
        //get the values from Table1 and insert it into Table2
    }
    sleep(1);
    if ($stop==1)
        echo stop;
    }
```

Please help me ..

Comment: Definitely don't use `sleep(1);`!

Comment: You will probably want to use `setTimeout()` on the client side and make a server request (somehow keeping state); upon the response you continue until the stop button is pressed ... don't do any sleeping on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It is working.

**Edited Code**

> repeatInsert.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['stopbutton']))
{
    echo "Stopped";
    exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['startbutton']))
{
    insertdata();
    exit;
}

function insertdata(){
    //Insert code here
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Repeated Insert</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Start Insert" name="startbutton" onclick="start();" />
        <input type="button" value="Stop Insert" name="stopbutton" onclick="stopInsert();" />
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var intervals;
            $(document).ready(function(){

            });
            function start()
            {
                startInsert();

                intervals = setInterval(startInsert, 1000);
            }

            function startInsert() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "repeatInsert.php",
                    data: {startbutton : true},
                    success: function(){
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            }

            function stopInsert() {
                clearInterval(intervals);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "repeatInsert.php",
                    data: {stopbutton : true},
                    success: function(){
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My html and php codes are in the same file.  I have two buttons "DataInsert" and "StopInsert".

Comment: Sorry Rads.. I am very new to web tech,so I have a doubt that how I will implement this when I have html, php codes in the same file.

Comment: I've put both html and php codes in the same file please check

Comment: I tried exactly the same code as you have given with my insert code..But it is inserting the data twice at the same time .. then    in function start()
            {
               intervals = setInterval(startInsert, 1000);
            }                                                                                                                   I removed calling the function startInsert for the first time. So, in this case it is inserting once at a time and not continously..

Comment: I am using jquery-1.11.3.js instead of jquery-1.11.3.min.js.. I hope that doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep checking the `$stop`  variable.  After the post is submitted your application wont know because the if statement has already been called.  You can fix this by checking it in your while loop.

Comment: @
itotallyrock.. I am not able to check the variable inside while loop. Once while loop is getting started, how to check whether stop button is clicked or not.. Is it by using javascript?? but thats also not working.. Please help. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what would happen if you're doing that:

```
CLIENT              |    SERVER
                    |
+--------+
|        | stop = 0
|   *----|--------> +------+
|        |          | loop |
|        |          |      |
|        |          |      |
|        |          |      |
|        |          |      | stop = 0
|   *----|---------------------------> +------+
|        |          |      |           | loop |
|        |          |      |           |      |
|        |          |      |           |      | stop = 1
|   *----|---------------------------------------------> +------+
|        |          |      |           |      |          | stop |
+--------+          |      |           |      |          +------+
                    +------+           |      |
                                       |      |
                                       |      |
                                       +------+
```

Within each invocation of the server side script, the value of `$stop` never changes.

What you will want to do is only perform one move operation in each run on the server side, and let the client side perform one request per one second interval.

It's your task to keep track of where you are in the move operation and synchronise that with the client side.